# Is there a way to read 10000 lines from a file in python?

Tags: python

I am relatively new in python, was working on C a lot. Since I was seeing so many new functions in python that I do not know, I was wondering if there is a function that can request 10000 lines from a file in python.

Something like this is what I expect if that kind of function exist:

```
lines = get_10000_lines(file_pointer)
```

Did python have a build-in function or is there any module that I can download for this?
If not, how do I do this to be easiest way. I need to analyze a huge file so I want to read 10000 lines and analyze per time to save memory.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You mean do your read in repeated 10000 line chunks?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there an equivalent function in C?

Comment: Thanks so much, sry to not paying attention to it, but thanks for help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
from itertools import islice

with open(filename) as f:
    first10000 = islice(f, 10000)
```

This sets `first10000` to an iterable object, i.e. you can loop over it with

```
for x in first10000:
    do_something_with(x)
```

If you need a list, do `list(islice(f, 10000))` instead.

When the file contains less than 10k lines, this will just return all the lines in the file, with no padding (unlike the `range`-based solution). When reading a file in chunks, EOF is signaled by there being <10000 lines in the results:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    while True:
        next10k = list(islice(f, 10000))  # need list to do len, 3 lines down
        for ln in next10k:
            process(ln)
        if len(next10k) < 10000:
            break
```

Comment: I'm quite fond of this solution. I'll add that you could do something like this to avoid using `break`: `iter(lambda: list(islice(f, 10000)), [])`.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do exactly what the OP wants. But it's almost guaranteed to be less efficient than ChipJust's answer. Reading however many lines there are in 512K requires a single read, and carrying over a buffer of half the average line length; reading 10000 lines pretty much has to mean either doing too many reads or carrying a larger buffer. That being said, I can't imagine when it would ever make a difference (and, if it did, you probably want mmap--or, better, change the data format so the problem goes away).

Answer (score 25):

> f.readlines() returns a list containing all the lines of data in the file. If given an optional parameter sizehint, it reads that many bytes from the file and enough more to complete a line, and returns the lines from that. This is often used to allow efficient reading of a large file by lines, but without having to load the entire file in memory. Only complete lines will be returned.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

This is not exactly what you were asking for, as this is limiting the bytes read instead of the lines read, but I think this is what you want to do instead.

Comment: Sorry for not having any votes left today, but I actually think this is a useful tip.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think OP needs this instead?

Comment: larsmans, which is up to the asker (and anyone else reading this question in the future) to decide. I think people are smart enugh to figure out which answers are applicable to their circumstances as long as they are given some of the alternatives.

Comment: He said "I need to analyze a huge file so I want to read 10000 lines and analyze per time to save memory." Using this feature of readlines is the correct and easiest way to buffer the reads, per the docs anyway.

Comment: @EmilVikström: I know -- I just felt I had to justify upvoting something that doesn't directly answer the question. Maybe that's stupid of me, I hope you didn't take offense.

Comment: +1. The fact that it's slightly more performant than reading exactly 10000 lines is nice, but the fact that it's a whole lot simpler is the real benefit here.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really care how many lines you have at a time? It usually makes most sense just to iterate over the file object, line by line:

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
```

The python documentation indicates that this is a preferred way to handle files:

> An alternative approach to reading lines is to loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simpler code.

See the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) for examples.

Comment: Why would it be slow? It likely uses deferred execution.

Comment: It will be slow because it will issue repeated reads. It's much faster to slurp as much text as possible before playing around with things like lines.

Comment: Then both of the other answers posted have the same issue.

Comment: @Marchin: it honestly depends on the work that you're doing on the file though.  Huge csv, wouldn't use a filereader, but if I did, I'd take chunks.  The works of Thoreau, replacing all 'turtles' with 'ducks' I'm sure this was is reasonable.

Comment: Jonathon, not necessarily. We don't know much about the work being done on the data so there may be some computation time between reads, at which point the disk drive may spin to other parts of the disk. Reading larger chunks at once may better make use of data locality.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier Right, whether or not you can tolerate slowness depends on the application. This is not the most performant way, which I assume OP wants, because they indicate they are using a large dataset.

Comment: @EmilVikström I argue the opposite. Marcin says this "will be slow because it will issue repeated reads", and from the python docs, I believe that calling `readline()` in a comprehension will do the exact same.

Comment: *I* say that it may be better to do all reading at one time instead of pausing for other work in-between. Multiple reads in fast succession is optimized by both the hardware and OS layers by read-ahead features.

Answer (score 3):

Just open the file and tell Python to read a line 10,000 times.

```
lines = None
with open('<filename>') as file:
    lines = (file.readline() for i in range(10000))
```

Comment: This will not put it in memory (if that's not what OP asked for, then I think it would be better...)

Answer (score 3):

Are you *sure* the file is too big for memory?

Since function calling has overhead (i.e. calling the same function 10000 times is slow) and memory is cheap, I'd suggest just reading all the lines at once and then slicing into the resulting list. This certainly the fastest way if you want to process the next 10000 later -- they'll be ready for you right away.

```
with open("filename") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

indices = range(0, len(lines), 10000) + [len(lines)]
for start, stop in zip(indices, indices[1:]):
    do_stuff_with(lines[start:stop])
```

Of course, if the file does not fit in free memory then this won't work. If so I'd go with [ChipJust's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091136/566644). You could even create a goal-seeking function using the `readlines` sizehint, [`tell`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell) and [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) that will "home in" on exactly 10000 lines, if that's important.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
while True:
    bytes_lines = f.readlines(10000) # read no more than 10000 bytes
    if not bytes_lines: break # stop looping if no lines read
    for line in bytes_lines:
        text = line.decode("knownencoding") # text will be a unicode object
```

It's faster to read a large amount of text at once, then process it. This reads chunks of texts, then splits it into lines for you. This saves on reads. It will also only give you complete lines, so you don't need to deal with joining the stubs of lines.

Do test this to ensure that reading from a file already at its end doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: +1 for a good alternative; but note that the `readlines` docstring says "Call readline() repeatedly and return a list of the lines so read." So it seems like this may not save on reads.

Comment: @senderle Thanks for mentioning that. It's not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Well, good way, but I actually need to read 10k lines not 10k byte, but thanks for contribute :)

Comment: @windsound Unless your computer has a magic line-oriented memory system, you need to limit the number of bytes you read, not the number of lines. Pick an appropriate number of bytes to read - 10000 is just an example.

Answer (score 3):

There is no function that works just as you want.  You can write one easily enough, but you may not be better off.  For example, if you get a list of lines as many of the solutions here show, then you have to analyze each line individually:

```
def get_10000_lines(f):
    while True:
        chunk = list(itertools.islice(f, 10000))
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk
```

If you do this, you might as well just read the file one line at a time, and analyze each string.  The file I/O will be buffered anyway:

```
for line in f:
    analyze_the_line(line)
```

if you want one string containing 10,000 lines, then you'll be reading each line individually and joining them together:

```
for chunk in get_10000_lines(f):
    str_10k = "".join(chunk)
    analyze_a_bunch(str_10k)
```

Now you are doing a lot of work to allocate and join strings, which may not be worth it.

Best would be if you could do you analysis on partial lines, then you can just read the file in 1Mb chunks:

```
while True:
    chunk = f.read(1000000)
    if not chunk:
        break
    analyze_a_bunch(chunk)
```

Answer (score 3):

Drawing from a couple of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091284/577088) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091142/577088), but adding a twist...

```
>>> with open('lines.txt', 'r') as lines:
...     chunks = iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(lines, 7)), [])
...     for chunk in chunks:
...         print chunk
... 
['0\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n', '6\n']
['7\n', '8\n', '9\n', '10\n', '11\n', '12\n', '13\n']
['14\n', '15\n', '16\n', '17\n', '18\n', '19\n', '20\n']
['21\n', '22\n', '23\n', '24\n', '25\n', '26\n', '27\n']
['28\n', '29\n', '30\n', '31\n', '32\n', '33\n', '34\n']
['35\n', '36\n', '37\n', '38\n', '39\n', '40\n', '41\n']
['42\n', '43\n', '44\n', '45\n', '46\n', '47\n', '48\n']
['49\n', '50\n', '51\n', '52\n', '53\n', '54\n', '55\n']
['56\n', '57\n', '58\n', '59\n', '60\n', '61\n', '62\n']
['63\n', '64\n', '65\n', '66\n', '67\n', '68\n', '69\n']
['70\n', '71\n', '72\n', '73\n', '74\n', '75\n', '76\n']
['77\n', '78\n', '79\n', '80\n', '81\n', '82\n', '83\n']
['84\n', '85\n', '86\n', '87\n', '88\n', '89\n', '90\n']
['91\n', '92\n', '93\n', '94\n', '95\n', '96\n', '97\n']
['98\n', '99\n']
```

But here I must admit that as others have said, using `readlines` with a byte hint is a bit faster, as long as you don't need *exactly* 10000 lines (or 10000 lines every time). However, I don't believe this is because it does fewer reads. The `readlines` docstring says "Call readline() repeatedly and return a list of the lines so read." So I think the speed gain is from cutting out some small amount of iterator overhead. Definitions (using Marcin's code):

```
def do_nothing_islice(filename, nlines):
    with open(filename, 'r') as lines:
        chunks = iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(lines, nlines)), [])
        for chunk in chunks:
            chunk

def do_nothing_readlines(filename, nbytes):
    with open(filename, 'r') as lines:
        while True:
            bytes_lines = lines.readlines(nbytes)
            if not bytes_lines:
                break
            bytes_lines
```

Tests:

```
>>> %timeit do_nothing_islice('lines.txt', 1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.6 ms per loop
>>> %timeit do_nothing_readlines('lines.txt', 7000) # 7-byte lines, ish
10 loops, best of 3: 56.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit do_nothing_islice('lines.txt', 10000)
10 loops, best of 3: 58.4 ms per loop
>>> %timeit do_nothing_readlines('lines.txt', 70000) # 7-byte lines, ish
10 loops, best of 3: 50.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit do_nothing_islice('lines.txt', 100000)
10 loops, best of 3: 76.1 ms per loop
>>> %timeit do_nothing_readlines('lines.txt', 700000) # 7-byte lines, ish
10 loops, best of 3: 70.1 ms per loop
```

On a file with average line length 7 (0 -> 1000000 printed line-by-line), using `readlines` with a size hint is faster by a bit. But only a bit. Note also the strange scaling -- I don't understand what's happening there.